# I want to implement QAbstractListModel for nested list and pass it from c++ to qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have implemented list using json for QAbstractListModel.
But dont have any idea to implement it for nested list. How the model will be linked to the sublist If my each element of list is having different sublist but same structure.
Any help or suggestions would be great help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: This sound like you need a hierarchical model. There is [tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html) from Qt on how to create a treemodel.